# Notify-send scripted to several other ubuntu's distros

Tags: ssh, lubuntu, notify-send

I start to wonder if it's possible to make a script to send notifications once to several other Ubuntus, i must say that not all the computers have the same Distro, having MATE XUbunutu LUbuntu and different versions.

It's reliable to do via ssh ??
It's a wide but closed network..

Any Ideas ? or any precedent of this Idea

Comment: FYI:  Lubuntu is a Ubuntu system with different installed packages, just as Ubuntu-MATE is also a Ubuntu system with different packages. For *lunar* or 23.04 the Lubuntu seed is [here](https://ubuntu-archive-team.ubuntu.com/seeds/lubuntu.lunar/desktop) and Ubuntu-MATE seed [here](https://ubuntu-archive-team.ubuntu.com/seeds/ubuntu-mate.lunar/desktop) ie. if release is the same all of Xubuntu, Lubuntu, Ubuntu-MATE are the same Ubuntu system with just different packages installed (due to different *seeds* putting different packages on ISO)

Answer (score 1):

yes try

```
ssh ip_addr "notify-send test123"
```

Comment: Hello! Good morning.
i got this error massage when i tried that.

ssh 10.7.81.17 "notify-send test123"
administrador@10.7.81.17's password: 
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.Notifications was not provided by any .service files

Comment: Ok. i just figure it out where was my error. I auth with the current user who is driving the session and work fine... BUT, there's no other change to auth as admin (which is the user all computers have in common) regardless they don't use it though